# Is there a way to implement health check for eventgrid triggered azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function which gets triggered when an event is published by a blob container. I just wanted to know if , it is possible to implement healthchecks for the function app. I came across implementation for blob trigger , queue trigger or azure bus services. I am using AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.

Answer (score -1):

The most important question is: why do you think you need health checks? The Azure platform manages everything around the Function App for you, which means you shouldn't be concerned about this. Those health checks are *for reporting the health of app infrastructure components*, which is specifically not your concern when using PaaS or FaaS.

That being said, please be advised that a blob trigger can, under certain conditions, take up to 10 minutes to actually trigger your Function. If you need this to be (near) real-time, consider using [Azure Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview).

> If your function app is on the Consumption plan, there can be up to a 10-minute delay in processing new blobs if a function app has gone idle. To avoid this latency, you can switch to an App Service plan with Always On enabled. You can also use an Event Grid trigger with your Blob storage account.

Source: [Azure Blob storage trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger)

Comment: A health-check can be useful for CICD pipelines to monitor whether or not the deployment was actually successful. Azure Functions as a platform service provides no way to determine this in all cases (for example, container deployments)

Comment: "A health-check can be useful for CICD pipelines to monitor whether or not the deployment was actually successful" This is true. That is however, IMHO, not a health check.